# Remove style attribute from all descendants in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm brand new to javascript/jquery, but have been going okay so far (though you'd hate to see my code), but I've hit a wall with trying to strip out style tags from some HTML I'm trying to clone.

The reason for cloning is that the CMS I'm forced to use (which I don't have access to code behind, only able to add code over the top) automatically builds a top nav, and I want to add a duplicate sticky nav once the user scrolls, but also add a couple of elements to the scrolled version.

The original HTML of the top nav looks a bit like like:

```
<nav id="mainNavigation" style="white-space: normal; display: block;">
    <div class="index">
        <a href="/participate/">Participate</a>
    </div>

    <div class="index" style="margin-right: 80px;">
        <a href="/news/">News</a>
    </div>

    <div class="index active" style="margin-left: 80px;">
        <a class="active" href="/about/">About</a>
    </div>

    <div class="external">
        <a href="/collection/">Collection</a>
    </div>

    <div class="index">
        <a href="/contact/">Contact</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I had mild success (other than those style tags I want to remove) with the following, even though it doesn't seem to make sense to me, as I expected some of the elements would be repeated (the whole < nav >…< /nav > tag should have been within the #mainNavigation clone, no?):

```
var originalNavItems = $('#mainNavigation').clone().html();
$("#site").prepend('
    <div id="ScrollNavWrapper">
        <div class="nav-wrapper show-on-scroll" id="mainNavWrapper">
            <nav id="newScrolledNav" style="white-space: normal; display: block;">
                <div class="index home">
                    <a href="/">Home</a>
                </div>
                ' + originalNavItems + '
                <div class="newItem">
                    <a href="http://www.externalsite.com">
                        View on External Site
                    </a>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>');
```

I've tried to use a few answers from related questions on here, but I keep getting incorrect results. Can you help me?

Comment: Also, FYI the html within .prepend('…') I used didn't have line-breaks, I just added those to try and clarify what I'm trying to do…

Comment: I don't see you trying to remove the style attributes anywhere and isn't that your main question?

Comment: So what are you trying to do exactly? Clone a navigation bar and add to it?

Comment: The `<nav></nav>` bits are part of your clone, but `.html()` returns the _inner_ html of that `<nav>`, i.e. not the tag itself.

Comment: Sorry @PeterHerdenborg – I mean, the above worked for the cloning and adding to the nav (@KyleT, yes that's correct) – but now I needed to remove the styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can strip the style elements like so:

```
var el = $('#mainNavigation'); // or whatever
el.find('[style]').removeAttr('style');
```

Comment: I think this might be the key element of my accidental solution below. Earlier I had been trying to declare a new variable like:

    var el = $('#mainNavigation').find('[style]').removeAttr('style');

with everything in one line, and it seemed to be only returning the elements that had included a style tag (with it now removed)… Breaking the find and remove portion into it's own line is the part that I think has fixed it?

Comment: The `find` will filter the elements to those that match the selector. You can use `end()` to get back to the pre `find` selector state. https://api.jquery.com/end/

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var originalNavItems = $('#mainNavigation').clone().find("*").removeAttr("style");
```

Then you can use `.append()` to add that html elements

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltu2L7h1/23/)

Comment: I had already tried this. From what I can tell, it seemed to be removing the div elements, but leaving their descendan a links or something weird???

Comment: I tried this again, it still wouldn't seem to work. Appending originalNavItems into another element put 'Object object' into the HTML, and appending originalNavItems.html() didn't seem to work at all.

While trying to debug it though I accidentally fixed the problem myself. I posted it below as an answer, I don't know if that's the wrong thing to do, but I figured if anyone else is looking for a similar problem then my solution, though not very elegant, might be helpful too… Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You can clone into an imaginary div and then fetch the `mainNavigation` also. You can also remove the style attributes along with that. Hope this works for you...

```
var temp = $('<div />').html($('#mainNavigation').clone());
temp.find('*').removeAttr('style');

originalNavItems = temp.html();
```

Comment: `.html($('#mainNavigation').clone())` will fail with an error if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg No, it works fine without any errors.

Comment: That's weird, as `.html()` takes a string, and `.clone()` returns a jQuery collection.

Answer (score 0):

The `nav` is cloned but the `html()` function only returns the HTML for the contents and that's why it disappears. You can avoid some string manipulation by adding the cloned element directly before a target element.

```
$("#site").prepend('
<div id="ScrollNavWrapper">
    <div class="nav-wrapper show-on-scroll" id="mainNavWrapper">
        <nav id="newScrolledNav" style="white-space: normal; display: block;">
            <div class="index home">
                <a href="/">Home</a>
            </div>
            <div class="newItem">
                <a href="http://www.externalsite.com">
                    View on External Site
                </a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>');

$('#mainNavigation').clone()
  .find('[style]').removeAttr('style').end()
  .insertBefore('#newScrolledNav .newItem');
```

In the previous case `find('[style]')` matches elements that have a `style` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Stack Overflow (and js in general), so this might be really bad ettiquette, but I seem to have accidentally fixed it myself trying to debug my implementation of the first upvoted answer that @Anoop Joshi gave above. Please comment and let me know if it would have been better to just edit my question!

I decided to break the process down into separate steps – similar to @Kiran Reddy's response actually, but I hadn't got to trying his yet.

I tried:

```
var styledHTML = $('#mainNavigation').clone();
styledHTML.find("div[style]").removeAttr('style');
var originalNavItems = styledHTML.html();
$("#site").prepend('<div… etc.
```

with a console.log(styledHTML) etc under each line to check what I had at each stage – and it worked! (The code did, console.log didn't?)

I was just doing this to try and log the value of the variables at each stage, but whatever I did fixed it…

Now I need to figure out why I can't even make console.log(variable); work :-/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$('#mainNavigation').children().removeAttr('style');
```

Hope this will help you.